# Error when plotting in Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

In Octave 4.0.2 I have defined a function S as follows:

```
S = @(x) (Y(k)+((Y(k+1)-Y(k))/h(k)-(2*M(k)+M(k+1))*h(k)/6)*(x-X(k))+M(k)*(k-X(k))^2/2+(M(k+1)-M(k))*(x-X(k))^3/(6*h(k)))
```

When I call it to evaluate a number in the interval [X(k), X(k+1)] I get the result I expect, but when I try plotting it with the command:

```
fplot(S, [X(k), X(k+1)]); hold on;
```

I get the error "error: for A^b, A must be a square matrix. Use .^ for elementwise power."

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out that when passing a function to fplot it must be able to take a vector of inputs and return a vector of outputs.

Comment: You may be able to use ezplot to bypass that requirement, even though it's best to use vectorised functions there too. But in general your question is very badly phrased, there are 5 things in that anonymous function you have left undefined